# SCSS for adding left line to border not working

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I'm trying to had a button that in it's non-selected state looks just like a plain undecorated link.

When a user clicks on it I want to apply an class called "active".

In the active state, I want the left border of the button to turn blue.

Here is how I have my scss, but it's not working:

```
.case-nav-link {
  display: block;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size:16px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  margin:10px;
  padding:15px 10px;
  border-left:solid 6px transparent;
  &.active {
    border-left:solid 6px blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your markup seems to [work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/Justastudent/bk5dop53/) already. What is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a `<a>` for this purpose if you want the class to be added on click, use `<button type="button">` or `<span>` if you add it when page load your code works. check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdemytda/)

```
<a href="#0" class="case-nav-link active">something</a>

.case-nav-link {
  display: block;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  &.active {
    border-left: 6px solid red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dejan, but I'm actually trying to decorate the element that has an additional class of "active", so while the user is on that page, they see the left border.So the html element class is: <a class="case-nav-link active">Users</a>

Comment: @cnak2 do you want to remove the class if user clicks on other `case-nav-link` element?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use something like jQuery to add the class in a click event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.case-nav-link').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    
  })

})
```

```css
.case-nav-link {
  display: block;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size:16px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  margin:10px;
  padding:15px 10px;
  border-left:solid 6px transparent;
  
}

.active {
    border-left:solid 6px blue;
}
  
  
  /* added for testing */
  
  .container {width:500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<a class="case-nav-link" >Link</a>
</div>
```